# How does "Vino con vino" translate to "She came with wine"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, gramática

Why doesn't the above translate to "Wine with wine"?

Comment: For properly answer we need a context. First 'vino' may be from verb 'venir' or may be wine itself. There is such an expression to refer to unknown origin wine as "vino con vino".

Comment: @Envite This is the entire sentence. It's part of a spanish tutorial.

Comment: Then the correct answer is that of ntrx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is an entire sentence, this is clearly a case of two different words that happen to be written the same. [Él/ella] vino [a verb] con vino [a noun]. Hence `"She came with wine"`

Here are two more nice examples of the same.

> Q: --¿Usted no nada nada?
>
> A: -- Yo no traje traje.

-- You don't swim, do you?

-- I did not bring a swimsuit.

`Nada` (a verb): you swim

`Nada`: nothing

`Traje` (a verb): I brought

`Traje` (a noun): a suit

```
Why does it sound like the conjugation for "Yo" instead of "Él/Ella/Usted"?
```

Because it is a past tense. The verb "Venir" is very irregular.

Present `"Yo vengo"`, `"Él/Ella/Usted viene"`

Past `"Yo vine"`, `"Él/Ella/Usted vino"`

Answer (score 4):

When you say "Vino con vino" the first "Vino" is for the conjugation of the verb "Venir" ("To come")

Comment: Why does it sound like the conjugation for "Yo" instead of "Él/Ella/Usted"?

Comment: The conjugation for "yo" of the verb "venir" would be "Yo vine", not "Yo vino". The conjugation of the 3rd personal pronoun is "Vino", as in "Él/Ella/Usted vino"

Comment: Venir is an irregular verb.  The 1st person singular present conjugatino is `vengo`.. Even still, preterite conjugations for the YO form never end in an 'o'.. it's always going to be an 'e' or an 'i' depending on which which tier the verb is.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends of the context as most of the languages issues, a quote comes to my mind:
"Al pan, pan; al vino, vino." (Bread to the bread, wine to the wine) and it means something like keep the things in its place. If you say "vino con vino". I think it can be in some strange context like "Ella mezcló leche con agua y vino con vino." (She mixed milk with water and wine with wine) assuming there where two kinds of wine, maybe, i know it sounds crazy, but it really depends of the context. In spanish we often don't use the pronouns, so again, it will depends of the context becaus "vino" (came) is used with both she and he.

The word "vino" is the third person past of "venir" and for it yo should use: 
yo vine, tú viniste, usted vino, él/ella vino

Also if you want to use it in a sexual way, as in English (She/He came) you can use it, but you will have to add the pronoun "se" like this "Él/Ella se vino".

Comment: "tú/usted vino" es incorrecto, *tú viniste; él/ella/usted vino*

Comment: Gracias, missed that one.

Answer (score 3):

"**Vino**" can mean two unrelated things. A substantive: wine. And a verb, third singular person, past tense of "venir" : (he/she/it) came.

It's just a case of [homonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym). English (most languages, I guess) also have them. 
Examples: "I'll **book** this **book**." "**Can** you pass me that **can**?"...